# must have an IF in my Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is how I will find out about my like a true or false, and I will do my Repeater.

If my like is false then the display content. but if it is true then the display content on the page.

Right now makes this error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterReport" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%--I have much more different content here.--%>
    <% if (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("like")) != true)
      { %>
      <a href="../mentor/report.aspx?like=<%# Eval("IdBesked") %>" class="btn btn-success mr-xs mb-sm">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Synes godt om
      </a>
    <% } %>
    <%--I have much more different content here.--%>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Error are here:

```
<% if (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("like")) == false) {%>
```

Select data:

```
var MentorBeskedReport = from mb in db.MentorBeskeds
                             where mb.Id == beskedId && mb.Til_BrugerId == Helper.ReturnBrugerId() && mb.godkendt == true && mb.opretdato < months
                             select new
                             {
                                 IdBesked = mb.Id,
                                 Navn = mb.brugere.fornavn + " " + mb.brugere.efternavn,
                                 dag = mb.opretdato,
                                 tekst = mb.tekst,
                                 like = mb.like // Bit in database TRUE/FALSE
                             };


    if (MentorBeskedReport != null)
    {
        //Report
        RepeaterReport.DataSource = MentorBeskedReport.ToList().OrderByDescending(i => i.IdBesked);
        RepeaterReport.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `Eval` method inside an `if` statement.

You should change your `a` tag to `runat=server` and give it an `ID`. Then, instead of doing the validation inside your `.aspx` file, you should add an `ItemDataBound` event and check it on `.aspx.cs`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterReport" ItemDataBound="RepeaterReport_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <a id="myAnchor" runat="server" href="../mentor/report.aspx?like=<%# Eval("IdBesked") %>" class="btn btn-success mr-xs mb-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Synes godt om
      </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

```
public void RepeaterReport_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "like")) != true)
        {
            ((HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("myAnchor")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be very hard to do when I pull my data off with LINQ.

Comment: @NickWillumsen You can use `Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "like"))` instead of `((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).like` if you want.

Comment: @NickWillumsen You can bind your Repeater with any kind of data you want, it doesn't matter. The `ItemDataBound` event occurs after the databinding, as soon as the item was bound, and it performs the changes you want to render your item correctly.

Comment: i cant not find `ItemDataBound` but i can find `OnItemDataBound`

Comment: now its make error here:

`<a id="myAnchor" runat="server" href="../mentor/report.aspx?like=<%# Eval("IdBesked") %>" class="btn btn-success mr-xs mb-sm">
                                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Synes godt om
                                </a>` and its say : **The server tag is not well formed.**

Comment: @NickWillumsen That's because you're using double quotes on both `href` attribute and `Eval`. You must change the attribute as follows: `href='../mentor/report.aspx?like=<%# Eval("IdBesked") %>'`.